# Google Analytics reports that referred visitors come in an an unexpected landing page that isn't where the link is pointing

Tags: google-analytics, redirects, landing-page, bounce-rate

There is this website's page (similar to reddit) which references my website's main page.

I recently realized an increase on my bounce rate. Then I checked and saw that in the last 10 days, users coming to my website from this web page above has an unexpected landing page, which is not my site's main page, but a specific product page.

This issue occurred on the last 10 days, and I really don't have any clue on what's going on.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

P.S: This happened before for a different product page. I removed that product page, and redirected it to my main page. However this time it occurs for a different page. The product page seems to be really random.

Comment: Put in a redirection at the missing page.

Comment: It is expected that other sites will deep link to specific pages within your site and will refer visitors to something other than your home page.   Why would that be a problem?

Comment: @Steve doesn't gives me a long term solution, it happened before for another page.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that other site is not giving a deep link to a specific page. It's giving a backlink to my main page. In that other site, I have written the description and I have given the link. It's kind of a introductory article. The problem is users coming from this article (which I created) lands on a specific procut page (this link is really random, and not included in the paragraph), which causes a higher bounce rate.

Comment: "The problem is _users_ coming from this article" - are you sure this involves multiple/different users? It's just that the "% New Sessions" and "New Users" columns are both _zero_.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a good look around your site and the only thing I can see what might be causing this is the that there appear to be 2 versions of tagmanager running. 
I can see a Global site tag (gtag.js) that is set up incorrectly, and a GTM that is running perfectly.

This might be the issue, but definitely worth checking. Also, is there anything odd about the pageviews or time on site?